# Using AngularJS in App With Multiple Endpoints

Tags: angularjs

I am learning about AngularJS. I have a basic web app that has three screens. The three screens are: Home, Product Listings, and Product. The "Home" screen is a basic welcome screen. The "Product Listings" screen will show a list of dozens of products. Each product can be seen in greater detail by selecting it on the Products page. From there, they will be shown more details in the "Product" view. As they navigate around the app, I want to use the ng-view to provide a smooth animation between the pages.

My files are arranged as follows:

```
Index.html
Index.html.js
Views
  Home.html
  Products.html
  Product.html
```

When a user uses my app, they may enter it from two different locations. They may start the app by visiting `http://www.mysite.com` or `http://www.mysite.com/products/{productID}`. productID is a dynamic value. When a user navigates to http://www.mysite.com, I know how to get everything working. However, my challenge is dealing with the scenario where someone visits a product and building everything the other way.

Does anyone know how to create an Angular app where a user may enter via either the root of an app or the leaf node of a sitemap? Essentially, I have a site with multiple endpoints.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using $route / $routeProvider?  Check them out here: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

I would also seriously take a look at yeoman to build a starter app for you.

http://yeoman.io

With yeoman you can simply create a scaffold for an app using best practices by installing the `generator-angular` generator for yeoman - it's all there on the site under 'getting started'.